# Py2Neo V4 - Function even when string value

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Code I execute:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship        
g = Graph(url + '/db/data/', username=username, password=password)
query = '''MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.name='Test' RETURN n '''
tmp = g.run(query)
tmp = tmp.to_subgraph()
print(type(tmp.values))
print(tmp.values)
```

Result I get:

```
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
<built-in method values of Node object at 0x7f9da8b2d888>
```

What I ll expeceted is a string value.Because the node looks like this:

```
n

{
  "name": "Test",
  "values": "Basic information",
  "type": "data"
}
```

The type-property can be printed easily...Someone has an idea? My assumption is NULL value or some hidden function...or is values a keyword?

Comment: Yes "values" seems to be a keyword / function for a Node ->  i changed to "valuelist" and it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://py2neo.org/v4/data.html?highlight=values#py2neo.data.Record.values

Yes values is a keyword - so do not name a property values if you afterwards wants to access the property again.